# ASP.Net Web API: Content based routing

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api

What are the possible ways of performing "content based routing" in ASP.Net Web API? Does it provide something out of the box as provided by WCF ([WCF Content based routing](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/owainwragg/archive/2009/07/22/content-based-routing-with-wcf.aspx))

Comment: I haven't seen anything that would allow this to happen. WebApi is configured in such a way that it doesn't really "inspect" the payload that you send it (because you can't read the inbound stream more than once). Why wouldn't you just have a strategy or something to handle it within the controller itself? Seems odd to have to scan multiple endpoints based on the payload that is sent.

Comment: I think this would be a nice feature, the routing would be based on the contents of the Content-Type header provided by client (similar to how routing is already done based on the http verb which is just another http header). One sidenote @Chris - it's easy to read the same payload multiple times, it's just a stream. You just have to remember to do a request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) when you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override SelectAction method in ApiControllerActionSelector class where you can inspect request's contents and determine which action method to use (using reflection). Then, simply return an instance of ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor passing in the current controller context and MethodInfo of the reflected action method. If no matching method is found, simply call base and return that result.

A sample can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16545954/1402786